# How to use the MUI X DataGrid API in a TypeScript application that is not fully React based

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I need to use the MUI X DatGrid in a TypeScript web application that is not fully react based but sometimes only uses individual React components.

The following [example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hill-kgrh25?file=/demo.tsx) shows a prototype on how to create a functional API.

The idea is to use the GridApi to functionally interact with the grid component but the code seems pretty ugly and I'm wondering:

- is there a smarter way to do this?
- why do i need the setTimeout before I can retrieve the `GridApi`?
- is there a way to force the DataGrid to refresh without changing any properties?

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {StyledEngineProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';
import {DataGrid, useGridApiRef} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

import type {GridApi} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
export type apiRefType = React.MutableRefObject<GridApi>;

type GridPropsType = {
  hideFooter: boolean,
  setApiRef: (ref: apiRefType) => void,
};


const Grid = ({setApiRef}: GridPropsType): JSX.Element => {
    const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

    setApiRef(apiRef);

    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
                <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
                    <DataGrid columns={[]} rows={[]}apiRef={apiRef} />
                </div>
            </StyledEngineProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
};

export const renderGrid = async (target: HTMLElement, hideFooter: boolean): Promise<apiRefType> => {
    let apiRef: apiRefType | null = null;
    const setApiRef = (ref: apiRefType): void => {
        apiRef = ref;
    };

    return new Promise((resolve) => { // eslint-disable-line promise/avoid-new
        ReactDOM.createRoot(target).render(<Grid hideFooter={hideFooter} setApiRef={setApiRef}/>);
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (apiRef === null) {
                throw new Error('apiref was not initialized');
            }

            resolve(apiRef);
        }, 0);
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olivier Tassinari offers an excellent solution in this [SR](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/9721)

```js
import { renderGrid } from "./demo";

const cols = [{ field: "username" }, { field: "age" }];
const rows = [{ id: 1, username: "@MUI", age: 20 }];

(async () => {
  const target = document.getElementById("root");
  const gridApi = await renderGrid(target, {
    hideFooter: true
  });
  gridApi.current.updateColumns(cols);
  gridApi.current.updateRows(rows);
})();
```

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { DataGrid, DataGridProps, useGridApiRef, GridApi } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<Partial<T>, K> & Omit<T, K>;

export type apiRefType = React.MutableRefObject<GridApi>;

type GridPropsType = {
  options: Optional<DataGridProps, "rows" | "columns">;
  setApiRef: (ref: apiRefType) => void;
};

const Grid = ({ setApiRef, options }: GridPropsType): JSX.Element => {
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setApiRef(apiRef);
  }, [setApiRef, apiRef]);

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <div style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
          <DataGrid columns={[]} rows={[]} apiRef={apiRef} {...options} />
        </div>
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

export const renderGrid = async (
  target: HTMLElement,
  options: GridPropsType["options"]
): Promise<apiRefType> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // eslint-disable-line promise/avoid-new
    ReactDOM.createRoot(target).render(
      <Grid options={options} setApiRef={resolve} />
    );
  });
};
```